# Setting permissions for document and all its subcollections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am getting the error:
`FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions` when trying to view a document in a subcollection. I'm trying to get at the documents 'character' in  subcollection 'settings'.

```
systemsCol()
  .doc(localStorage.getItem("systemId"))
  .collection('settings')
  .doc('character')
```

How can i set all items and subdocuments for each 'system' document?

Here are my permissions

```
service cloud.firestore {
    function authed (auth, data){
    return auth.uid == data.owner.uid || auth.token.email in data.collaborators;
  }

    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /systems {
      allow read, write: 
        if request.auth.uid != null;

      match /{systemId}  {
        allow list, create:
            if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow get, update, delete: 
          if authed(request.auth, resource.data);
            }

      match /{systemId}/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: 
            if authed(request.auth, resource.data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also tried

```
service cloud.firestore {
    function authed (auth, data){
    return auth.uid == data.owner.uid || auth.token.email in data.collaborators;
  }

    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /systems {
      allow read, write: 
        if request.auth.uid != null;

      match /{systemId} {
        allow list, create:
            if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow get, update, delete: 
          if authed(request.auth, resource.data);

                match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write:
            if authed(request.auth, get(/systems/{systemId}).data);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your rules have a lot of conditions that you're not saying anything about here, so it's not really possible to pinpoint what's going wrong.  I suggest you eliminate all the conditions except one, make sure that one works, then keep adding in conditions until it works the way you want.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I have a high level collection called systems. Each can have an owner and many collaborators. (verified by uid of owner and email of collaborators)


The auth permissions on the systems collection and each system document work, but I'm having issues when trying to access subcollections with the same account.